# Re-initializing a react sub-form for reuse

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

This is obviously something I don't know how to do... It's conceptual.
My use case is an input form for a purchase (or an invoice, or whatever) that has header data and detail data.
My user sees a listing of purchases, a line per purchase.
She clicks one and sees its detail items, the original single line expands to display item lines, any number of them.
Below the last one there is an "add item" [＋] button.

Upon clicking the [＋] button the "new item" form shows, below the current items.
The user fills the sub-form and clicks the "save" [✔] button (which is enabled only once the item is OK).
The data that was in the form now appears in a line, as a the last item of the purchase. Until now nothing new, nothing to complain about.

As the user is adding items at the end of this particular purchase (perhaps loading it into the system for the first time) I want she to be shown the purchase item sub-form again, and again, until she clicks the "close" [] button.
  [image: A screen capture of the forms, "new item" is the lower half]

This is what I can't find how to do, after days trying and reading.
For example, the second time the form shows with the same previous data content again, which is unacceptable (because it fosters data duplication by mistake). I need to clear state.

I can initialize the form in its constructor, which only works for the first use.
Currently I clear the data after the user clicked the "save" [✔] button, and this works, but I'm not happy with it, because this it's sort of a "footings" time while initializing is more of a "headings" thing.

I cannot initialize at the top of render() because it runs a gazillion times, all inputs are controlled and change the local state like crazy.
Also, setState() from within render() loops forever.

I'm about to try with getDerivedStateFromProps but the official React literature is trying to discourage me.

Is "getDerivedStateFromProps" the right place to clear a form before reusing it, or is there a better approach?
I'm aware that getDerivedStateFromProps also runs many times, so I'll need to set a "thisFormNeedsToBeInitialized" flag whenever the user hits the "save" [✔] button.
The getDerivedStateFromProps method runs as many times as render() but it seems that I'll be able to setState() from whthin it.

Answer (score 0):

Reading more about my question's subject, I found an article by @bvaughn that explains how to do what I want.
It's [an article about "derived state"](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key).
In short, it says that if I give each consecutive instance of my repeating form a different `key` then React destroys the previous instance on re-render, so I can initialize each new instance in the constructor (which is a "headings" time situation.

I didn't try it yet, but I'm pretty sure it's a good solution.
Especially, a cleaner solution than the one I was planning with `getDerivedStateFromProps`.